# IOS: Fetch core data through one to many relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, one-to-many

I have a data model with several entities.  For entities joined in one-to-one relationships, after a fetch from one entity, I am able to access an attribute from the other entity through the relationship.

```
//class for artists

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
@class Songs;

@interface Artists : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * artistname;
//this is relationship
@property (nonatomic, retain) Songs *songs;

//class for Songs
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
@class Artists;

@interface Songs : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * songname;
//this is relationship
@property (nonatomic, retain) Artists *artists;
```

If the relationship is One-to-one, once I have performed a fetch of artists and have a managedobjectcontext, I can get the song of each artist using the following:

```
NSLog(@"song for one hit wonder%@",self.artists.songs.songname);
```

When I change the relationship from one-to-one to one-to-many, i.e. one artist, many songs, this no longer works and throws an error that references `[_NSFaultingMutableSet songname`

I have tried to access the song using value for key without success.

```
NSLog(@"songs:%@",self.artists.songs.valueForKey[@"songname"]);
```

Also, I've tried to incorporate NSSet somewhere since the error message references mutable set and one-to-many relationships are supposedly captured that way but I cannot figure out how to use NSSet.

```
NSSet *songs = self.artists.songs.songname;//gives incompatible pointer type warning
```

Any suggestions one how to retrieve values from another entity in the case of a one-to-many relationship would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's a bit confusing to set the name of a Core Data entity to a plural form because it suggests always *many*.

If you change the relationship in the model from one-to-one to one-to-many you have to change the type in the `NSManagedObject` subclass to `NSSet` for example

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *songs;
```

You can prove it by recreating the `NSManagedObject` subclasses automatically in Xcode.

Comment: OK.  So NSString will change to NSSet?

Comment: I changed NSString to NSSet and still get [_NSFaultingMutableSet song name error

Comment: I updated the answer. The easiest fix is to recreate the `NSManagedObject` subclasses in Xcode.

Comment: Your answer makes sense but recreated and still getting same error.

Comment: Assuming you have an `Artists` instance named `johnDoe`, you get the songs with `NSSet *songs = johnDoe.songs;` and a song name with `Songs *song = [songs anyObject];` `NSString *songName = song.songname;`

Comment: This has prevented error I was getting before but am getting null for song when there is a song.

Comment: Maybe – for some reason – the class is not firing faults (loads related objects lazily).

Comment: The model instance is loaded lazily.  However, there must be a standard way to access data from another entity with a one to many relationship as this use case has to be pretty common.  Frustrating.